# QTCreator 2.3 Locals and Watches not populating for Qt classes

Tags: qt-creator

So when i hit a break point in my program, the watches window populates as it should. However when i expand a Qt class (QObject, QWidget, QImage etc) the arrow opens but no new information populates the window. Literally all that changes is the expanding arrow. So far the only Qt class that works in the watch window is QList.

The other issue i'm having is that sometimes the expand arrow is now listed at all.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Any help will be appreciated.

I am using QtSDK 1.1.3
Debugger helpers are on.